# How to setup LDAP authentication with WP multisite

Tags: multisite

I would like to set up my WP multisite install so that it will authenticate with our LDAP server. I had this working using the [WPMU LDAP authentication plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpmuldap/), but it no longer appears to be working with WP 3.9.1 and MySQL 5.3. Other plugins I've tried seem to call for the plugin to be configured on every site, and I would prefer for something to work over the entire network.

Can anyone explain how to go about setting up my WP multisite installation running WP 3.9.1 to  authenticate over LDAP?

Answer (score 1):

This is a recently updated plugin that should allow you to authenticate via LDAP:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/auth0/

It supports LDAP SSO as well as a bunch of other authentication methods. It says it supports multiple WordPress instances, so I assume that means multisite as well.

Hope this helps!